# Next.js: how to create entry browser history

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, next.js, next-link

I have been trying to create an entry in the browser history every time I navigate to a new page in Next.js with the Link property provided by them, but I am not able to push an entry to the browser history, so if I go back one page I am not on the page before on my application, but on the page of whatever else I visited before.

Does anyone know how to implement this functionality in Next.js? Also, I have a node back end, if that is useful in any way.

Comment: Please see [ask]. You're expected to show your effort as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably the only way I found of creating browser history in nextjs

[React & Next.js — Bug: getting previous page's value from session storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68521626/react-next-js-bug-getting-previous-pages-value-from-session-storage)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).